# Handling space in module name sonarqube runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have an existing sonar-runner that is working correctly like so:

```
sonar.modules=old-project1,old-project2
```

However I am adding a new module (new project3) to the runner but the module has a space in the project name so my new module line looks like this:

```
sonar.modules=new project3,old-project1,old-project2
```

I get errors for Sonar including "ERROR: Unrecognized option: project3,old-project1,old-project2" or "PROJECT:new project3" is not a valid project or module key. Allowed characters are alphanumeric, '-', '_', '.' and ':', with at least one non-digit."

It seems obvious to me that a space is not a legal character for the sonar runner modules but just wanted to confirm this or see if there is a work around as I am new to Sonar.

*Project names are changed from the actual implementation.

Comment: Maybe the empty space is not allowed, I can't see any information about that on the documentation, you can try this also:  sonar.modules=old-project1,old-project2,new project3

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I did give this a shot however it leads to similar errors. The space seems to be interpreted as an end in the line of information. Regardless of it's positioning I think the space will cause an issue. I might have to rename the project to get the project into Sonar. Double quotes have been similarly ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that spaces are not allowed in project keys. I feel that the `Allowed characters are alphanumeric, '-', '_', '.' and ':', with at least one non-digit` error message is explicit enough - but feel free to challenge if you don't agree.

Comment: You'll also see this odd error if you have a space character in your `settings.gradle` -> `rootProject.name = 'My App Project'`, for example. It's not obvious at all, and unclear why SonarQube even cares about project name.

Comment: What is the recommended workaround ? We have more than 100 modules that use "-" in the name.